# AWS Personalize: how to deal with a huge catalog with not enough interaction data

Tags: amazon-web-services, recommendation-engine, amazon-personalize

I'm adding a product recommendation feature with Amazon Personalize to an e-commerce website. We currently have a huge product catalog with millions of items. We want to be able to use Amazon Personalize on our item details page to recommend other relevant items to the current item.

Now as you may be aware, Amazon Personalize heavily rely on the user interaction to provide recommendation. However, since we only just started our new line of business, we're not getting enough interaction data. The majority of items in our catalog have no interaction at all. A few items (thousands) though get interacted a lot, which then impose a huge influence on the recommendation results. Hence you will see those few items always get recommended even if they are not relevant to the current item at all, creating a very odd recommendation.

I think this is what we usually refer as a "cold-start" situation - except that usual cold-start problems are about item "cold-start" or user "cold-start", but the problem I am faced with now is a new business "cold-start" - we don't have the basic amount of interaction data to support the a fully personalized recommendation. With the absence of interaction data of each item, we want the Amazon Personalize service to rely on the item metadata to provide the recommendation. So that ideally, we want the service to recommend based on item metadata and once it's getting more interactions, recommend based on item metadata + interaction.

So far I've done quite some researches only to find one solution - to increase explorationWeight when creating the campaign. As [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-personalize-can-now-create-up-to-50-better-recommendations-for-fast-changing-catalogs-of-new-products-and-fresh-content/) indicates, *Higher values for explorationWeight signify higher exploration; new items with low impressions are more likely to be recommended.* But it does NOT seem to do the trick for me. It improves the situation a little bit but still often times I am seeing odd results being recommended due to a higher integration rate.

I'm not sure if there're any other solutions out there to remedy my situation. How can I improve the recommendation results when I have a huge catalog with not enough interaction data?

I appreciate if anyone has any advice. Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 1):

The [SIMS recipe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-sims.html) is typically what is used on product detail pages to recommend similar items. However, given that SIMS only considers the user-item interactions dataset and you have very little interaction data, SIMS will not perform well in this case. At least at this time. Once you have accumulated more interaction data, you may want to revisit SIMS for your detail page.

The [user-personalization recipe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-new-item-USER_PERSONALIZATION.html) is a better match here since it uses item metadata to recommend cold items that the user may be interested in. You can improve the relevance of recommendations based on item metadata by adding textual data to your items dataset. This is a new Personalize feature (see [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/unlock-information-in-unstructured-text-to-personalize-product-and-content-recommendations-with-amazon-personalize/) for details). Just add your product descriptions to your items dataset as a textual field as shown below and create a solution with the user-personalization recipe.

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Items",
  "namespace": "com.amazonaws.personalize.schema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ITEM_ID",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "BRAND",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "categorical": true
    },
    {
      "name": "PRICE",
      "type": "float"
    },
    {
      "name": "DESCRIPTION",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "textual": true
    },
  ],
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

If you're still using this recipe on your product detail page, you can also consider using a [filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/filter.html) when calling GetRecommendations to limit recommendations to the current product's category.

```
INCLUDE ItemID WHERE Items.CATEGORY IN ($CATEGORY)
```

Where $CATEGORY is the current product's category. This may require some experimentation to see if it fits with your UX and catalog.

Comment: In the first paragraph of user-personalization recipe it says "with based on Interactions, Items, and Users datasets." well, I can see your answer is from 2y ago - so perhaps what you described was valid back then ?

Comment: The user-personalization recipe has always considered interactions (required), items (optional), and users (optional) datasets. The OP was asking about item cold start, which is supported by user-personalization and leverages item metadata. I did not mean to imply that interactions and users data were not used as well. In fact, interactions are required by all recipes. Something that has changed since my answer is the addition of the Similar-Items recipe which can recommend cold items for related items use cases.

Comment: Thanks @James - I have similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77651961/content-based-recommendation-using-amazon-personalize where my emphasis is on how to do content-base with AP if possible. seems  Similar-Items recipe is sth new. does it make sense to share your expeirence with Similar-Item recipe on my question ? 
Thank you.